# Bevelling edge at the center doesn't take the shape of the object

Tags: bevel, loop

[image]

I'm trying to bevel the center loopcut that I made but the bevel doesn't take the shape of the object. I have tried applying the rotation and scale but that had no effect. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the edge. use the percent setting to make the beveling follow the profile. [image]

Comment: Amazing! this was it thank you so much!